# How to record and run Test Cases in JIRA?

Tags: unit-testing, jira, jira-plugin

I have a web application which I need to continuously and rigorously test and automate the testing process on JIRA.

I use JIRA Cloud subscription.

How do I implement the below requirements on JIRA:

1 - Writing Use Cases (user stories) and have them saved as items on JIRA so that I can easily find, search, and filter them on JIRA (same as I can do with Issues for example).

2 - Creating Test Cases by recording them while I test the test case manually the first time (same as recording a macro in Excel) and then be able to re-run the test cases anytime I want again and recording the output each time I run them.

- Each Test case created should be linked to its parent Use Case.
- Each Use Case can have many Test Cases linked with it.
- a Test Case could be associated with multiple Use Cases.

3 - Running all recorded Test Cases in batches and capturing the output for each run of each test case, and then manually judging whether the test case succeeded or failed for that run.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Zephyr plugin for JIRA? https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je/cloud/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some, but not all of what you describe is possible with out-of-the-box JIRA.

It is possible to create a custom issue type of 'Test Case'. You can give this issue type all the fields that are appropriate for a test case.

Having the custom issue type makes it easier to do searches (e.g. search for all open issues of type 'Test Case' on a project).

JIRA allows you to have many-to-many relationships using [issue links](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/linking-issues-776997756.html). Unfortunately searching using issue links is a pain unless you have a plugin like [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview). Script runner gives you functions like [hasLinks, linkedIssueOf and epicsOf](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_issue_links).

If you want to do more sophisticated linking of actual tests with JIRA then it would be worth considering some of the test plugins, such as [Zephyr](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je/cloud/overview). This plugin allows you to create and execute tests from within JIRA.

Another thing that is worth considering is JIRA integration with source control systems. For example, JIRA has good [integration with GitHub](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/connect-jira-cloud-to-github-814188429.html). It would be possible to store your test cases under source control and then link them to JIRA issues as a part of the commit process.

Answer (score 0):

New tickets in JIRA can also be created using REST API call, below are few links which refers sub ticket creation call with examples. Hope this helps!!

- https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue
- https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/